# EACCES: permission denied with Node JS

Tags: node.js, fs, file-access

I get below error when write a file (file name is book) with Node.js, could you please help?

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/book'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1163:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/remoteserver/ionicappGate.js:375:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
```

The code is as below

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = "/book";

//do whatever required after initialize
fs.writeFileSync(path, "hello book");
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Platform Server running on port 4000'))
```

Comment: can you try to give absolute path ? Like const path = "./book" or you can try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to write to the root of your file system "/book".  This is probably write protected (default in Linux).  If you really mean to write to that directory, check to make sure the user running the node process has write permissions to that folder.  Otherwise, change to the path relative to the script such as ./book and again make sure the user running the node process has write permissions to that folder.

Answer (score 3):

I hope the script command below may resolve your problem:

```
 chmod -R 755 book/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check permissions to file with **[fs.access(path[, mode], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)**.

Also check your folder permissions. Read more detail about file system permissions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)